# How is L2 (ridge) penalty calculated in sklearn LogisticRegression function?

Tags: python-3.x, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

For example when executing the following logistic regression model on my data in Python . . .

```
### Logistic regression with ridge penalty (L2) ###
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
log_reg_l2_sag = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', solver='sag', n_jobs=-1)
log_reg_l2_sag.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
```

I have not specified a range of ridge penalty values. Is the optimum ridge penalty explicitly calculated with a formula (as is done with the ordinary least squares ridge regression), or is the optimum penalty chosen from a default range of penalty values? The documentation isn't clear on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question. You want to know how the 'L2' regularization works in case of logistic regression. Like how the optimum value is found out.
We don't give a grid here like [0.0001, 0.01 ] because the optimum values are found out using the 'solver' paramter of the LogisticRegression. 
The solver in your case is Stochastic Average Gradient Descent which finds out the optimum values for the L2 regularization.
The L2 regularization will keep all the columns, keeping the coefficients of the least important paramters close to 0.

Comment: Thanks Vatsal - so the SAG solver is finding not just the regression coefficients but the penalty value as well?

Comment: In any linear problem the objective is to minimise the loss function  plus the regularization parameter. So, you can say the sag is optimising the combination of loss function and regularization term. For eg - The objective function is *Loss Function + alpha(L2) . So this optimum alpha term is what you are looking for I think. This is find out using the SAG